# Adding Horizontal and/or Vertical borders with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, activex, excel-2016

When a checkbox is unchecked E4:F11 is hidden.
When it is checked the cells are visible and formatted.

I need more.

The first thing is this code creates a border around the range, which I do want.
Is there was a way to do horizontal and/or vertical borders on a certain range?
For example on the screen shot below, I want thin borders on the bottom of E5:F5, bottom of E7:F7 and the bottom of E9:F9 and still keep the thick borders on the whole range (E4:F11).

Second thing; is there was a way to only change the colors of some of the cells.
For instance on this screenshot I want E5, E7, E9, and E11 white filled (the rest the red color).

I am using ActiveX Checkboxes and ActiveX buttons on other parts of the sheet.

This is for work so I cant upload the sheet but I can answer questions and upload more screenshots if needed.

```vb
Private Sub CheckBox5_Click()
    With ActiveSheet
        If .Range("E4").Interior.Color = vbWhite Then
            
            With .Range("E4:E11", "F5:F11")
                .Interior.Color = RGB(220, 86, 65)
                .Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            End With
          
            Range("E4:E11", "F5:F11").BorderAround _
              LineStyle:=xlContinuous, _
              Weight:=xlThick, _
              Color:=RGB(0, 0, 0)
          
        Else
          
            With .Range("E4:E11", "F5:F11")
                .Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
                With .Borders
                    .LineStyle = xlNone
                End With
            End With
          
        End If
      
    End With
End Sub
```

Screenshot
[image]

Comment: Sorry but I don't really understand the issue. The question doesn't even have a question. But if the issue is that you only get borders around then that is due to `Range("E4:E11", "F5:F11").BorderAround _`

Comment: Your promised screenshots are missing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Toggle Cell Formatting

```vb
Private Sub CheckBox5_Click()
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ActiveSheet
        If .Range("E4").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then
            With .Range("E4:F11")
                .EntireRow.Hidden = False ' ?
                .Interior.Color = RGB(220, 86, 65)
                .Font.Color = vbBlack
                With .Range("E5,E7,E9,E11")
                    .Interior.Color = vbWhite
                End With
                .BorderAround xlContinuous, xlThick, vbBlack
                .Rows(2).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Rows(4).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Rows(6).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
            End With
        Else
            With .Range("E4:F11")
                .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
                .Font.Color = vbWhite
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
                .EntireRow.Hidden = True ' ?
            End With
        End If
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate the areas in the range. Other [options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.borders) are `xlDiagonalDown, xlDiagonalUp, xlEdgeLeft, xlEdgeRight, xlEdgeTop, xlInsideHorizontal, or xlInsideVertical.`

```vb
Dim a As Range
With ActiveSheet
    For Each a In .Range("E5:F5,E7:F7,E9:F9").Areas
        a.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    Next
End With
```

Comment: Thank you, where do I put this in the code? After the End With? I keep getting an error when i attempt to put it there.

Comment: Put the `For Each/Next` block inside your existing `With ActiveSheet` block. Put the `Dim` before `With` block. What error were you getting ?

Comment: okay, i got it to work but I have to remove the  all around  thick border. is there a way to do both? https://pastebin.pl/view/beb0c227

Comment: You can add another line `a.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThin`  (other options are `xlMedium` or `xlHairline`)